# Use an induction argument to prove that for any natural number $n$, the interval $(n,n+1)$ does not contain any natural number.

Tags: induction, natural-numbers

> Use an induction argument to prove that for any natural number $n$, the interval $(n,n+1)$ does not contain any natural number.

I don't know where I could go with an induction argument. I was thinking of proving that if $s\in (n,n+1)$, where $s$ is a natural number, then $s-n$ is a natural number which lies in $(0,1)$, which is impossible as all natural numbers are bounded below by $1$.

However, this assumes that natural numbers are closed under addition. Also, this does not use induction.

Any pointers for this question?

Comment: When you consider $s-1$ instead you could set up an induction.

Comment: @quid- The only way that I can think of using induction is that if $s\in (n,n+1)$, then $s+k$ is an integer for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$. However, how do I arrive at a contradiction through this method?

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: How do you define $n<m$ for natural numbers $n,m$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen- By whether $m-n>0$ or $-(m-n)>0$? I'm sorry I don't understand the reference to this question.

Comment: The definition of $<$ is essential to answer the question.  If you defined $<$ to order the natural numbers as ${0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7 \dots}$ then there would be, for example, a natural number in $(4, 5)$.  So you have to know what the definition of $<$ is and use it.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan So you do ont work with $\Bbb N$ alone, but instead consider it a subset of a larger structure (such as $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb R$) where subtraction is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Every natural number except $0$ is the successor of a natural number.  The proof is by induction: the statement is vacuously true for $0$; and if it holds for $n$, it holds for $n+1$.
2. Every natural number is $\ge 0$.  Again, by induction: true for $0$, and if $n\ge 0$, then $n+1\ge 0+1 > 0$.

Now suppose $q$ is a natural number strictly between $0$ and $1$.  Since $q$ is not zero, it is the successor of some natural number $q'$ (by 1.) that is $\ge 0$ (by 2.).  But $q'\ge 0$ implies that $q=q'+1\ge 0+1=1$, which contradicts the assumption that $q<1$.  Therefore there is no natural number between $0$ and $1$.

Finally,

3. For any natural number $n$, there is no natural number between $n$ and $n+1$.  We've just proven the base case ($n=0$).  And if there were a natural number $q$ between $n+1$ and $n+2$, then it would be the successor of some $q'$ (by 1.), and that $q'$ would have to lie between $n$ and $n+1$, because if $q'\le n$ then $q=q'+1\le n+1$, and if $q'\ge n+1$ then $q=q'+1\ge n+2$.  Therefore, if the statement holds for $n$, it holds for $n+1$.

Comment: You are also borrowing the (inductively establishable) lemma that $a < b$ and $b < a$ are exclusive.  Also that $ \le $ is preserved under adding $1$.

Comment: @DanielV I am curious, how would you show $a<b$ and $b<a$ inductively? I think I see a way you can do it using double induction but that seems rather silly since it follows from the definition in two steps. Please let me know if there is an easier induction I am missing.

Comment: @SE318 You have to establish that $\exists k ~:~ a + k = b$ and $\exists j ~:~ b + j = a$ implies that $a = b$, which follows from some lemmas about addition (associativity and injectivity).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:

If there is no $a\in \mathbb{N}$ in $(n,n+1)$ then consider $(n+1, n+2)$. If there where a natural number, $b$, in $(n+1, n+2)$ there would be a natural number in $(n,n+1)$ since $b-1$ is also a natural number, but this is false by hypothesis.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the proof. How it is true that if $b$ is a natural number then so is $b-1$? This isn't true for $b=1$, for example. Also, I feel that we need to prove the base case, which is that there is no natural number in $(1,2)$. How does one go about doing that?

Comment: This proof begs the question.

Comment: We can start the induction from $n=2$. As to proving in detail that there is no natural number in $(1,2)$ I think that is not the focus/intention of the question. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Daniel- We have to prove that this is satisfied for **all** natural numbers $n$. Hence, ignoring the $n=2$ case might not be the best strategy

Comment: We don't ignore it. Clearly there is no natural number in $(1,2)$ and for the base case $n=2$ again clearly there is no natural number in $(2,3)$.

Comment: Also keep in mind, this is just a hint and not a full solution.

Comment: You don't really need to start the induction from n=2. After you show it holds for n=1, then you can assume n>1 and show it holds for n. You always do this anyways in induction(because you can't show the first one by induction!) so you don't need two base cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions $(\forall n \in \mathbb N)(\exists k \in \mathbb N)$:

- **(1)** $k \ne n $
- **(2)** $k \ne n+1 $
- **(3)** $\exists y \in \mathbb N ~:~ n + y = k $
- **(4)** $\exists z \in \mathbb N ~:~ k + z = n + 1 $

Some lemmas to borrow (would have to be inductively established using peano axioms and definition of $+$):

- **(5)** Addition is commutative/associative
- **(6)** Addition is injective : $a + x = b + x \implies a = b$
- **(7)** Every natural number is either $0$ or it has a natural number predecessor
- **(8)** Zero has no predecessor

Your task is to prove that the above is inconsistent.

Starting with **(3)** and **(4)**:

$$(\exists y \in \mathbb N ~:~ n + y = k )\land (\exists z \in \mathbb N ~:~ k + z = n + 1 )$$
$$(\exists y \in \mathbb N ~:~ n + y + 1 = k + 1) \land (\exists z \in \mathbb N ~:~ k + z = n + 1 )$$

Apply **(5)**

$$(\exists y \in \mathbb N ~:~ n + 1 + y = k + 1) \land (\exists z \in \mathbb N ~:~ k + z = n + 1 )$$
$$\exists y,z \in \mathbb N ~:~ (n + 1 + y = k + 1 \land k + z = n + 1 )$$
$$\exists y,z \in \mathbb N ~:~ (k + z + y = k + 1)$$

Apply **(5)**

$$\exists y,z \in \mathbb N ~:~ (z + y + k = 1 + k)$$

Apply **(6)**

$$\exists y,z \in \mathbb N ~:~ (z + y = 1)$$

Now the problem is reduced to establishing that (over natural numbers) $z + y = 1 \implies z = 0 \lor y = 0$ .  Assume for the sake of contradiction that $z \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$, then by **(7)**

$$p(z) + 1 + p(y) + 1 = 1$$
$$p(z) + p(y) + 1 = 0$$

Which contradicts **(8)**.  So $z = 0$ or $y = 0$.  However the first contradictions **(2)** and the second contradicts **(1)**.

Comment: I hope that the solution that I’ve provided below meets your standards. =)

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing actual puzzle in the question when I say the following:
First step in induction is to show that it holds for $n_{0}$ and in this case it is obvious that it hold for $n_{1}=1$ the second step is to assume the hypothesis at hand holds for $n_{k}$ and the last step is to use second step to show it must hold for  $n_{k+1}$.
So assume it does not hold for $k+1$ then there exists a natural number $s\in(k+1,k+2) $ then this gives the desired contradiction since $s-1\in(k,k+1) $ means $n_{k}$ does not hold. 
Then $(0,1)$ does not contain any natural number can be stated separately.

Hope i am not stealing anybody's time by missing the point.

Comment: How do you prove that there are no natural numbers in the range of $(0, 1)$?  Maybe the questioner is supposed to take it on assumption, but seems like the more difficult part of the question.

Comment: We know the natural numbers are $1,2,3...$. Since the numbers $(0,1)$ can be written as $a = 1-\epsilon$ where $0< \epsilon <1$ we can see that    it is impossible for there to be a natural number in $(0,1)$. @DanielV Would this be enough?

Comment: I think here 0 is considered to be a natural number, and if we start natural numbers with 1 danilesIV's comment will be about $(1,2)$ then. I have been away from abstract math for a long while so I am not that confident but ability to show the initial step or the hardness of it is not about difficulty of the induction, is it ? I mean in any sort of proof one would come across a problem like that, if one cannot show the statement is true for one natural number, how can you show it for all natural numbers?

Comment: @Daniel There are 2 kinds of proofs : those where you are establishing something in doubt, and those where you are establishing something intuitively obvious.  In the first type, feel free to make handwaving head-in-the-cloud arguments, and to use intuition freely.  In the second case, since you are establishing something intuitive, it is more of an exercise "are you capable of using a logical calculus".  Assumptions must be enumerated, all steps must be justified.  That's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

You must know the following:

> $\mathbb{Z}$ is a "well-ordered" ordered ring. Here, well-ordered means that every non-empty subset bounded by below has minimum.

Whatever definition you are using, you must fall in the above fact.

From that, we prove the following:

**Proposition:** There is no natural number $x$ such that $0 < x <1$.

*Proof:* Take the set $A:=\{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid 0< n<1\}$. Supposing it is not empty, we would have a bounded by below non-empty subset. Therefore, it has a minimum $m$. But $0 < m² <m<1$, a contradiction with the fact that $m$ is the minimum of $A$.

The induction is as others (and also you) pointed out.

I could avoid talking about integers, and stay on $\mathbb{N}$. But the notation for concisely saying the properties that $\mathbb{N}$ should satisfy as an algebraic structure would be too cumbersome, I think. (Maybe not... defining something such as an "ordered monoid" but with two operations etc etc.)

Comment: Your proof involves circular reasoning because a proof of the Well-Ordering Principle would require the fact that for any $ m \in \textbf{N} $, there does not exist an $ n \in \textbf{N} $ such that $ m < n < m + 1 $.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, recall that
$$
m \leq n
\stackrel{\text{df}}{\iff}
(m,n \in \textbf{N}) ~ \text{and} ~ (\exists k \in \textbf{N})(n = m + k)
$$
and
$$
m < n \stackrel{\text{df}}{\iff} (m \leq n) ~ \text{and} ~ (m \neq n).
$$
It is easy to prove that $ \leq $ is a reflexive and transitive relation on $ \textbf{N} $. To establish its anti-symmetry, we need a lemma.

> **Lemma.** If $ n \in \textbf{N} \setminus \{ 0 \} $, then there exists an $ m \in \textbf{N} $ such that $ n = m + 1 $.

*Proof*. Let
$$
A = \{ n : \textbf{N} \mid (n = 0) ~ \text{or} ~ (\exists m \in \textbf{N})(n = m + 1) \}.
$$
Clearly, $ 0 \in A $, and if $ n \in A $, then $ n + 1 \in A $ also, because there exists an $ m \in \textbf{N} $ such that $ n + 1 = m + 1 $. Therefore, by the Principle of Induction, $ A = \textbf{N} $, which yields the lemma. $ \qquad \square $

> **Theorem.** $ \leq $ is an anti-symmetric relation on $ \textbf{N} $.

*Proof*. Let $ m,n \in \textbf{N} $, and suppose that $ m \leq n $ and $ n \leq m $. Then there exist $ k,l \in \textbf{N} $ such that
$$
n = m + k \qquad \text{and} \qquad
m = n + l.
$$
Consequently,
$$
  n
= m + k
= (n + l) + k
= n + (l + k).
$$
By the Cancellation Law for $ + $, we find that $ l + k = 0 $. If $ k = 0 $, then $ l = l + k = 0 $. If $ k \neq 0 $, then the lemma says that there exists a $ j \in \textbf{N} $ such that $ k = j + 1 $, so
$$
  0
= l + k
= l + (j + 1)
= (l + j) + 1.
$$
This is a contradiction because $ 0 $ is not a successor. Therefore, $ k = 0 = l $, which yields $ m = n $. $ \qquad \square $

> **Proposition.** Let $ m \in \textbf{N} $. Then there does not exist an $ n \in \textbf{N} $ such that $ m < n < m + 1 $.

*Proof*. Assume the contrary, i.e., there exists an $ n \in \textbf{N} $ such that $ m < n < m + 1 $. Then there exists a $ k \in \textbf{N} $ such that $ n = m + k $. As $ m \neq n $, we have $ k \neq 0 $. By the lemma, there exists a $ j \in \textbf{N} $ such that $ k = j + 1 $, so
$$
     m + 1
\leq (m + 1) + j
=    m + (1 + j)
=    m + (j + 1)
=    m + k
=    n.
$$
We thus have $ n < m + 1 \leq n $. As $ \leq $ is an anti-symmetric relation on $ \textbf{N} $, we obtain $ n = m + 1 $, contradicting $ n < m + 1 $. $ \qquad \square $